# For mobile wallets that don't ask for a password, how are keys encrypted on your device?

Tags: encryption, wallet-security

I've used wallets that give a seed phrase, but don't ask for a password to send coins (signing a transaction).
I can't imagine they encrypt with the seed phrase since you don't ever re-enter the seed phrase to send a tx (only to restore an account on another device). I also can't imagine they would store the private keys in plaintext on the device.

So how does the mobile wallet access the private keys to sign your transaction when you send coins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the wallet doesn't ask you for your seed phrase every time you need to sign a transaction, the logical conclusion is that it is indeed storing your private keys. The specific method and security measures might vary between apps and operating systems, but one such method is the [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).